# Complete requested API address list for Microsoft Azure Cognitive Service TTS API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am testing Azure TTS service and it is working well on my dev PC.

Now, I am test on a windows server in a secure data center.

However, it may not work because of company firewall system which blocks both inbound/outbound traffic.

So, I need complete API address list to open firewall.

I am using C# and Azure Cognitive Service Nuget package.
I initialize SDK using “SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(key, region)”.

I found that some related address in Azure API help page and Github sample as the followings for southeastasia;

https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken

https://southeastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1

Could you please let me know whether it is right?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, that is right !

The endpoint is usually of the below type :

```
https://<REGION_IDENTIFIER>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/ #for token
https://<REGION IDENTIFIER>.tts.speech.microsoft.com #for other communication
```

Region Identifier is the region shortened.

The API reference for text to speech is detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-curl).

Alternatively, if you are looking to allow all Azure cloud traffic. The below would be complete list. This would be the recommended approach (The below is Public Cloud, For US gov you could refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls?tabs=us-government-cloud)).

```
*.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com
*.aka.ms
*.applicationinsights.io
*.azure.com
*.azure.net
*.azurefd.net
*.azure-api.net
*.azuredatalakestore.net
*.azureedge.net
*.loganalytics.io
*.microsoft.com
*.microsoftonline.com
*.microsoftonline-p.com
*.msauth.net
*.msftauth.net
*.trafficmanager.net
*.visualstudio.com
*.windows.net
*.windows-int.net
```